# Special Form of "I", "Me"

Tags: pronouns, coordination, case, grammar-myths

I have two sentences:

1. > John, Jane, and **I** went to the party.
2. > He and **I** went to the party.

But I think there is a rule that says a pronoun at the end of a list should be in a special form (for "I", the special form is "me").  So, my sentence 1 and 2 should be rewritten like this:

3. > John, Jane, and **me** went to the party.
4. > He and **me** went to the party.

But in a lot of writing, sentences like sentence 1 and 2 are used instead of sentence 3 & 4.  Is there a special rule that allows not using "me" for sentences similar to 1 and 2 for casual writing?

Comment: It might be a duplicate, but the answer there is wrong, so it doesn't really answer this question . . .

Comment: @snailboat: That's what other answers are for ;)

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are correct. 3 and 4 are common, but incorrect. It's not the position in the sentence that makes the difference, but whether you are the subject or the object.

Use "me" when you are the object:

> He gave it to me.

Use "I" when you are the subject:

> I went fishing

When combining yourself with another as the subject, place yourself last:

> He and I went fishing.

When combining yourself with another as the object, place yourself first:

> He gave it to me and my brother.

Comment: Even though I know you're right,  I still can't convince myself that the last form sounds right! Native speakers get this wrong. A lot.

Comment: Yes @JosephRogers, we do.

Comment: I agree with all of this except for the last part. I think in combined objects, "me" can come first or last. "Me and my brother" sounds good because the "me" sets the stage for the possessive "my" in "my brother." But in a sentence like "He gave it to you and me," it sounds fine to put "me" last.