# "John and I are friends" vs. "John and me are friends"

Tags: word-order, coordination, personal-pronouns, case

I was corrected in the middle of a conversation because I used "John and I are friends" as opposed to  "John and me are friends."

I think the former sounds correct, but am not sure. Could someone help?

Comment: The former ("John and I are friends") is considered "correct" from a prescriptive point of view. The latter is common colloquially, but I don't think it's common enough to make the first sound wrong to a majority of speakers (from a descriptive standpoint). I would say the person who "corrected" you put their foot in their mouth. The sentence was fine the way you said it.

Comment: Related: [Is it “he” or “him” in the sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100010), [When to use I vs me](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82481), [Special Form of “I”, “Me”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71751)

Comment: Actually, even in colloquial speech, "John and me are friends" seems less likely than a third option, "Me and John are friends."

Answer (score 0):

One would say *I am friends with John*, not *Me am friends with John*.

Hence I am convinced you are right and it should be *John and I are friends*.

But one might say *Harry is friends with John and me*.

Answer (score 0):

"I" and "me" are both first singular pronouns. They are used by a person to refer to himself; however, "I" is the doer of the action while "me" is the receiver of the action.

That is why grammarians and teachers insist on using "I" when it is in the place of a subject and "me" when it's in a place of an object.

So the formal choice, especially in writing, is

> John and I are friends.

and it is considered the correct form because if you take "john" out, the sentence is transformed to

> I am a friend.

The subject pronoun remains the same and there is a consistency.

Further reading:
http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/when-to-use-i-and-when-to-use-me